# ID Attribute Error Django Admin in Change Form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to pass `Nation` model id to Django admin `change_form` so I can show a button or two when editing. I tried passing the id to the render_change_form function and finish up in the template, but I'm getting the below error.

```
'NationAdmin' object has no attribute 'nation_id'
```

N:B This works fine when editing but it will throw this error when I want to add a new model object via Django Admin dashboard.

Methods under NationAdmin

```
  #this method is to get the id
   def change_view(self, request, nation_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.nation_id = nation_id
        return self.changeform_view(request, nation_id, form_url, extra_context)

 #for form
 def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.nation_id: #django is telling me this line is causing error
             nation= self.get_object(request, self.nation_id)
             context.update({'nation':nation})
        return super(NationAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

Change_form.html

```
   {% if not nation.is_moderated and not nation.is_rejected %} 
      <a href="{% url 'activate_moderation' nation.id %}"> <input type="button" value="{% trans 'Approve' %}" name="_approvebutton" /></a>
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `original`. No need of setting `nation_id`

```
 def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        if context.get('original'): #
             obj = context['original']
             #this will be the object you are trying to update
        return super(NationAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: okay.. where does the `original' comes in? A keyword in model admin?

Comment: Its the keyword using in admin which will be the object you are changing. If it is add new object, it will be None. Thats why i put if condition

Comment: Okay let me try it. Thanks!

Comment: Tried it out. I got reversematch error with the template. So I changed it to this:  def render_change_form(self, request, obj, context, *args, **kwargs): if context.get('original'):
            obj=context['original']
            
        return super(NationAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, obj, context, *args, **kwargs)  And got TypeError: render_change_form() got multiple values for keyword argument 'obj' What do you think is missing?

Comment: It is not depend on the above answer. It will be `"{% url 'activate_moderation' nation.id %}"` .You need to fix that

Comment: Yeah, fixed it with {% if original %} #do this and dat {% endif %}